# Automating git commit message per branch

Tags: git, bash

I keep finding myself forgetting to add refs #ticket to my commits. It's a pain. I usually use at least one branch per ticket, or at least, there might be mutliple branches for one ticket, but usually not the other way around.

So I was thinking of something like add a branch.ticket config option and then retrieving it from probably prepare-commit-msg and prepending "refs #" to my message.

Maybe after this is done, even adding a hook or an alias to ask for a #ticket when I create a new branch.

Can someone help me build these? I'm fairly new at git, and am no bash guru either, but I can figure it out if pointed in the right direction.

By now, I gather I have to call

```
git config --add branch.<branchname>.ticket <ticketnumber>
```

and then do something like

```
prepend `git config branch<branchname>.ticket` $file
```

basically. I think.
Anyone can confirm this? and tell me how to get < branchname >?

Comment: Not really an answer, but I love the way that git lets you amend the previous commit in case you forgot or mistyped something (such as the commit message).

Answer (score 2):

This sounds good. You can get the current branch name (if there is one) with `git symbolic-ref HEAD`.

You might want to cut off the `/refs/heads/`. I'm using this in my prompt script:

```
local branchname=$(timeout 1s git symbolic-ref HEAD 2> /dev/null | cut -b 12-)
```

and then a check on being the empty string.

Comment: could you explain or point me to where I get that -b 12- cut parameter explained, please?

Comment: `cut -b 12-` ignores first 12 bytes of input

Comment: that's what I thought.. isn't that a bit restrictive? couldn't the branch syimref name be different?

Answer (score 0):

You are on right track I believe

There are many ways to get the current branch:

```
git branch | grep '^*' |sed s/\*\ //
```

Or use `git symbolic-ref HEAD` and get the last part after `/`